# Ending a while loop if a variable is less than or equal to zero in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop

For a school project, I have been making a game which allows the user to guess the end result of a football match and be able to bet on there prediction. I have been trying to break the while loop if their balance is less than or equal to zero but have been unable to do so. The whole Python code is much more extensive than what's shown below but this is the only problem.

```
tries = int(input("How many attempts would you like : "))

while balance > tries:
   while guesses < 2:

        print ("\nYour current balance is : £",balance)

        gameresultguess = input("\nWho will win - Home, Away, or Draw : ")
        bettingchoice = input("Would you like to bet this round - Yes or No : ")

        while True:
            if str.lower(bettingchoice) == "yes":
                bet = int(input("How much would you like to bet : "))
            if bet > balance: break
            print ("You have insuficient funds to bet this much, please try again")

        guesses +=1

        hometrue = random.randint(1,7)
        awaytrue = random.randint(1,5)

        if hometrue > awaytrue:
             gameresulttrue = "home"

        if awaytrue > hometrue:
             gameresulttrue = "away"

        if hometrue == awaytrue:
             gameresulttrue = "draw"

        if str.lower(gameresultguess) == gameresulttrue:
             print ("Correct! Nice guess! The final score was ",hometrue," : ",awaytrue)
             if str.lower(bettingchoice) == "yes":
                  balance = (balance + bet)
                  print ("Well played! Your bet has been doubled and added to your balance")
             if str.lower(bettingchoice) == "no":
                  print ("Unlucky... Should have placed a bet")

        else:
             print ("Unlucky! The final score was : ",hometrue," : ",awaytrue)
             if str.lower(bettingchoice) == "yes":
                  balance = (balance - bet)
                  print ("Oops... Better luck next time")

print ("Ouch... You went bankrupt. Try coming back when you have more money")
```

Comment: I don't see where you've tried this. You have other break statements in your code, so should be straight-forward to say if balanace <= 0: break. Can you explain why you haven't been able to and what you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

When you call break, it is breaking out of your current loop.

```
while True:
    if str.lower(bettingchoice) == "yes":
        bet = int(input("How much would you like to bet : "))
    if bet > balance: break
    print ("You have insuficient funds to bet this much, please try again")
```

In your example, I believe you're referring to the loop where balance is lower than bet, you are trying to end the game?

To do this, you can make this logic into a function and return the "result" of the bet. Or if you prefer to keep the current structure, you can raise an exception and catch to print the final "bankrupt" message.

```
class InsufficientFundError(Exception): pass

try:
    while balance > tries:
        while guesses < 2:
            ...
            while True:
                ...
                if bet > balance:
                    raise InsufficientFundError()
except InsufficientFundError:
    print("Ouch... You went bankrupt. Try coming back when you have more money")
```

Answer (score 0):

*"I have been trying to break the while loop if their balance is less than or equal to zero but have been unable to do so."*

Which while loop are you trying to break if the balance is less than or equal to zero? I'm assuming the "biggest" one that you've posted, since it wouldn't make sense that one could continue betting with negative balance.

To do this, you must set it in the initial condition. Try:

```
while balance > 0:
```

With this, your "betting process" that is nested under this loop will cease when the user reaches a negative balance, or runs out of money.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help!!

After reading the answers I saw it was just my mistake of breaking the statement early. Sorry for the problem.

Thanks again :)